# Overlapping of XAML elements

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am writing a canvas program, where on scale of canvas , it is occupying the row above to it. I understand this is a normal behavior that XAML read topdown.

So i am re-arranging the top row of the grid to the bottom of the document, I could able to overcome with the problem.

When i same the document, document format pref is making back to the top of the document.

Is there any thing like Zindex kind to keep the row on top most irrespective of the location in the document.

Example :

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
<Label Grid.Row="0"/>
<Canvas Grid.Row="1"/>
<Label Grid.Row="2"/>
```

When i Zoom Canvas, it is covering the label in Grid.Row="0".

Answer (score 2):

Got it! It is `Panel.ZIndex="<number>"`. Thank you